# Is it possible to view average system performance/load over time on a default installation of Windows Server?

Tags: performance, windows

Without previously configuring collector sets, is there any record of performance metrics kept on a default installation of Windows Server?

I have been tasked to evaluate the load on a particular server. I can setup collector sets and comeback after some time has passed, but I was wondering if there might be something I could look at now.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is not. This is why collector sets exist, as you've discovered.

Comment: Or, possibly, if your environment already has a centralized performance monitoring system, like Solarwinds Orion or SCOM, you might find the history there. Of course, we can't answer that, unless we're your co-workers.

Comment: @mfinni yeah definitely. I made the leap of faith that if the OP had to ask this question, he doesn't have centralized monitoring/trending in place :)

Comment: Sure sure. But if he/she is the new person on staff, it's not a given.